# How to connect Oracle database from Robot Framework without any client installed

Tags: oracle, robotframework, jython-2.7

Most solutions requires some client installed or cx_Oracle module using which is not appropriable as well - because i have to use Jython version of the Robot Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd researched a lot of posts just to have a very simple solution:

1. Install [DatabaseLibrary](http://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/api/0.6/DatabaseLibrary.html) module by

   ```
   pip install robotframework-databaselibrary
   ```
2. Install [JayDeBeApi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/JayDeBeApi/) module by

   ```
   pip install JayDeBeApi
   ```

   - *now you can put these libraries anywhere you like - just copy them from Python\Lib\site-packages*
3. And here is going the trick!
   The DatabaseLibrary usage have following sample for jaydebeapi connection:

   ```
   Connect To Database Using Custom Params | JayDeBeApi | 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver', 'my_db_test', 'system', 's3cr3t'
   ```

However this is **wrong**! You have to use the brackets over the username-pass pair! Like this:

```
Connect To Database Using Custom Params | JayDeBeApi | 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver', 'my_db_test', ['system', 's3cr3t']
```

And please do not forget to use URL connection instead of my_db_test! It should be like this:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//127.0.0.1:1521/my_db_test
```

Hope it will helps someone! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using robot framework with Java, then there is separate library available on robot official site : http://robotframework.org/#libraries
   with name **Database Library(Java)**
2. Download this library and put it into lib folder
3. Download drivers required for oracle and put it into lib folder

Define following variables in your file

```
${ORACLE DATABASE URL}           jdbc:oracle:thin:@${DATABASE_IP}:1521:${ORACLE_SYSTEM_ID}
${ORACLE DATABASE USER}         ${DATABASE_NAME}
${ORACLE DATABASE PASSWORD}     PASSWORD
${ORACLE DATABASE DRIVER}       oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Use below keyword to connect to database

```
Connect To Database      ${ORACLE DATABASE DRIVER}      ${ORACLE DATABASE URL}  ${ORACLE DATABASE USER}   ${ORACLE DATABASE PASSWORD}
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed the Library  DatabaseLibrary and  jaydebeapi but in the code it doesn't recognize the JaydeBeApi and didn't worked.

This is how i resolved my problem.

I had to install Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 from http://aka.ms/vcpython27 after that i followed this steps

1. open a command window (start -> cmd)
2. git clone https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_oracle.git cx_Oracle
3. cd cx_Oracle
4. git submodule init
5. git submodule update
6. pip install cx_Oracle
7. pip install robotframework-databaselibrary
8. pip install JayDeBeApi(probably it will work for some one)

```
 *** Settings ***
Documentation  Basic database related keywords
Library  DatabaseLibrary

*** Variables ***
${DB_CONNECT_STRING} =  'user/mypasswd@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myipaddress)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=mysid)))'

*** Test Cases ***
Connecting
  connect

  @{queryResults}  Query  select * from table t where id_table =1001

  log to console  @{queryResults}

*** Keywords ***
Connect
    connect to database using custom params  cx_Oracle  ${DB_CONNECT_STRING}

Disconnect
    disconnect from database
```